# python Regular expression xx/xxx/

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Trying to use regular expression but struggling a bit, can you please advise

Below is the example that i'm trying to work on

import re

```
CommonPrefixes = {'Prefix': 'JG/BMF/'}

pattern = "\/"

result = re.sub(pattern,'',CommonPrefixes["Prefix"])

print(result)
```

**output**
JGBMF

**Expected Output should be as below**
BMF

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your regex substitution to do. There are many patterns that would produce the output `BMF`, but I imagine not all of them actually do what you want.

Comment: `regex101` is great for exploring **regex** patterns [link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks Guys! I've got it resolved now. I have used below (^\w\w)|(/)" re.sub("(^\w\w)|(/)",'',x["Prefix"])

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is change pattern = "/" to [/JG] , this is a group of char that regex will handle it

```
import re
CommonPrefixes = {'Prefix': 'JG/BMF/'}

pattern = "[/JG]"

result = re.sub(pattern, '', CommonPrefixes["Prefix"])

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amir, in Prod the String "JG" will change for every load i.e. for first load it could be 'JG, Second load it could be 'BV' etc.. So I have used the pattern "[\w/]" and the out i'm getting is "/BMF/" , "/BV/" ... but i'm expecting output as BMF,BV ...

Comment: Thanks Guys! I've got it resolved now. I have used below (^\w\w)|(/)"                re.sub("(^\w\w)|(/)",'',x["Prefix"])